Snapshot repository for ELK
We have ELK setup using ECK helm charts. I need to enable snap shot repository. When client name is given in kibana it shows below error Unknown client name [XXXXXXX]. Existing client configs: default"
Am not able to see any configuration showing default client name.
Can you please help

Repo created as per image
